# Where can latex classes ported to g/troff?

Tags: groff, troff

I’m becoming

- horrified at latex’s verbosity
- so excited by g/troff

But where can I find popular latex classes like ieeetrans or acmart ported to g/troff?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that both organisations only offer only Latex and Word templates. I don't know what these classes do (I don't use Tex), so I cannot say whether or not it is possible to create a macro set that provides comparable output.

Comment: no macro sets being tuned by lots of people? that's interesting.   i've seen  a lot of activity in youtube recently on g/troff. is that a just a quirk?  is n/troff not an active community?

Comment: I do use `groff`, and I have my own personal macro set, tuned to *my* specific needs. It's on github `https://github.com/ljmdullaart/in3xml` and called in.tmac. However, that is something completely different from matching a latex or word template form an official organization.